# Memory efficient way to compare adjacent records in pyspark

Tags: python, algorithm, apache-spark

I am looking for a memory-efficient way to create a column in a pyspark DF using a function that is taking as arguments values from 'adjacent' (i.e., when the dataset has been sorted on a particular column) records, which are permutations of a particular hash.

That is, for a particular dataframe, which has several 'hash_n' (up to ~five) columns, I am looking to sort on each hash column, and create a new column based on a function of the hash in 'this' column, as well as the next several (up to ~15) columns.  The function is essentially comparing the 'similarity' of the hashes and appending the 'index' of the 'other' column if the similarity is above some threshold.

Initially I was doing this with a window function and a pyspark UDF, but having run into outOfMemory problems, I am now converting to RDD, creating a dictionary of 'nearby' RDDs by incrementing the index, unioning the resulting dictionary values, and applying the function to the union via reduceByKey.  This approach seems to be an improvement, although I am still running into memory issues (yarn killing containers as result of executor using too much memory; have tried several settings without being able to get around this problem).

Here is the relevant part of the code I am using (it is slightly more convoluted as it has to allow for the possibility of a single column on which to partition (in terms of how the data is processed -- we only compare hashes if they are in the same partition) the data, 'partnCol', or else a list of the same, 'partnCols'; in practice we always have at least one partition column); the parameters here are nPerms, the number of times that the hash is permuted (so that we have a total of nPerms+1 hash columns), and B, the number of adjacent records to look at for matches.

```
HSHTBLDict = {}; rdd0Dict = {}; rddDictDict = {}
possMtchsDict = {}; mtchsDict = {}
for nn in range(nPerms+1):
    if (partnCol):
        HSHTBLDict[nn] = _addNamedDFIndex(HSHTBL.orderBy\
                            (partnCol, 'hash_{0}'.format(nn)), 'newIdx')
        rdd0Dict[nn] = HSHTBLDict[nn].select('newIdx', partnCol, '__index__', \
                                         'hash_{0}'.format(nn))\
             .orderBy(partnCol, 'hash_{0}'.format(nn)).rdd.map(tuple)\
                .map(lambda kv: ((kv[0], kv[1]), (kv[2:])))                
    elif (partnCols):
        HSHTBLDict[nn] = _addNamedDFIndex(HSHTBL.orderBy(\
                        *(partnCols+['hash_{0}'.format(nn)])), 'newIdx')
        rdd0Dict[nn] = HSHTBLDict[nn].select('newIdx', \
                    *(partnCols+['__index__', 'hash_{0}'.format(nn)]))\
             .orderBy(*(partnCols+['hash_{0}'.format(nn)])).rdd.map(tuple)\
                .map(lambda kv: ((kv[:len(partnCols)+1]), \
                                 (kv[len(partnCols)+1:])))                
    else:
        HSHTBLDict[nn] = _addNamedDFIndex(HSHTBL.orderBy(\
                                        'hash_{0}'.format(nn)), 'newIdx')
        rdd0Dict[nn] = HSHTBLDict[nn].select('newIdx', '__index__', \
                                             'hash_{0}'.format(nn))\
             .orderBy('hash_{0}'.format(nn)).rdd.map(tuple)\
                .map(lambda kv: ((kv[0], ), (kv[1:])))                                     
    rddDictDict[nn] = {}
    for b in range(1, B+1):
        def funcPos(r, b=b):
            return r.map(lambda kv: (tuple([kv[0][x] + b if x==0 else kv[0][x] \
                                        for x in range(len(kv[0]))]), kv[1]))
        rddDictDict[nn][b] = funcPos(rdd0Dict[nn])
    possMtchsDict[nn] = sc.union([rdd0Dict[nn]] + rddDictDict[nn].values())\
              .reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y, numPartitions=rddParts)\
              .mapValues(lambda v: tuple(v[i:i+2] \
                            for i in range(0, len(v), 2)))
    mtchsDict[nn] = possMtchsDict[nn].mapValues(lambda v: tuple([ tuple([ v[x][0],  \
                        [p[0] for p in v if _hashSim(v[x][1], p[1]) > thr]])\
                                        for x in range(len(v)) ]) )
# union together all combinations from all hash columns
Mtchs = sc.union(mtchsDict.values())
# map to rdd of (__index__, matchList) pairs
mls = Mtchs.flatMap(lambda kv: kv[1]).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: list(set(x+y)), \
                                                  numPartitions=rddParts)
```

If anyone has any advice / ideas would be very happy to listen to them.

I did try reducing the number of cores per executor, and I found that although the process was (comparatively very) slow I could get it to complete, although I have not yet found a combination of settings that work for the full range of nPerms / B that I would like to achieve.  Possibly it is necessary to re-work the code / approach in order to do that.  I would also like to understand better the way in which the amount of memory that yarn is allowed for things like shuffles is determined.  I have found that decreasing --executor-memory and increasing --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead seems to help, but it still not clear to me how one would calculate the amount of memory that will be available.

Comment: have you tried setting the number of cores per executor to 1. It will be slower but all the memory allocated to each executor will be used for each task

Comment: Can you update the question with current code and some sample data? I cannot imagine them from the description.